# Efficiently way of assembling PyTorch `Tensor`s that require gradients

Tags: pytorch, pre-allocation

I need to construct a 4-dimensional PyTorch `Tensor` where one of the dimensions comes from multiplying a constant [sparse matrix](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/sparse.html) with a dense vector. The dense vector, and the resulting 4D `Tensor`, require gradients to be tracked. Since PyTorch only supports sparse *matrices*, I can't express the whole thing as a `Tensor`-`Tensor` multipllication, and I think I have to do the matrix multiplication part of the construction in a loop. In that case, I'd at least like to preallocate the result 4D `Tensor` and let the sparse `mm` fill in one dimension in a loop.

How do I in that case keep track of the resulting 4D `Tensor`'s gradient requirements? Can I manually attach it into the gradient graph once it's been created?

My current approach is extremely inefficient, essentially building up one dimension at a time in a list, can `cat`ing.